# What is the total energy of a object if i throw it so far from the earth that it doesnt move towards earth? It seems there is energy loss

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy

Let us assume that i throw a object A with velocity V_A. Then it reaches certain height H_A. At that point it has total energy which is equal to its potential energy and it comes down converting PE to KE. But let us assume that i throw a object so far that it  doesn't move towards earth through Gravitational attraction.

Then one can see energy is lost but where ?

Comment: For an object not to feel a gravitational attraction towards Earth, it would have to be infinitely far away, which can't happen in reality. Energy is not lost, it's something that simply won't ever happen.

Comment: Then let us assume that there is only earth and one ball in universe . If i throw a ball i transfer it my energy.  As it goes up it gains potential energy and its Kinetic energy decreaes .Then  lets assume that its velocity becomes 0m per second 100000000000000000km away . Now will that ball again accelerate towards the earth.  And what is its total energy at a point when its velocity is zero?

Comment: Its total energy if it has no kinetic energy would be its gravitational potential energy only. That far away, it would be quite small, but it wouldn't be 0. That far away you would still be attracted to the gravitational potential, yes. Gravitational interactions have infinite range. The only way you ever escape a gravitational interaction is if your total energy is positive, i.e. you will always have more kinetic energy than you owe the potential to escape from it. Think of gravitational potential energy as an amount of energy you have to pay to escape the gravity jail.

Answer (score 0):

The gravitional potential function is zero at infinity by convention. So it is negative at the Earth surface.

$$V = -GMm/r$$

If a mass departs vertically (from above the atmosphere to avoid air resistance) with more than 11.2 km/s, the sum with the potential energy is positive.

$$E_k + V > 0$$

and it *escapes* the potential well and doesn't return.

Comment: Actually, just accelerating to 11.2 km/s while in orbit means you escape Earth either way. Doesn't need to be vertically up, you'll just follow a different trajectory, from a straight line to a hyperbolic trajectory.

Comment: As you said If the velocity is more than 11.2km/s then  then it will go outside the earth and doesn't return.  I have a question regarding that. Okay the ball has escaped the earth and now moving in space . At that point   what is its total energy?  My view upon this is :  if ball is not going to return then it doesn't have potential energy and it  has now lower velocity than 11.2km/s and now it seems its total energy is lesser . Where is its energy lost ?

Comment: @santoshchhetrithapa If you ever get to escape velocity, 11.2km/s on the surface of Earth, your total energy is 0, which means you don't owe the gravity jail anymore energy to escape from it, you could go infinitely far away. The moment you are over escape velocity, that means your total energy is positive, which means you could get to infinitely far away and still continue to have kinetic energy. If you have negative total energy, it means you still owe the gravity jail some energy if you want to get out of there, you'd always be pulled back sooner or later.

Comment: Then let us assume : we have only earth and a ball in universe and space and time are infinite. Then if i throw a ball with 11.2km per second that will move infinitely far as you said but the quenstion is gravitational field is infinite that means there is a attractive force between two even if it infinite distance away. That means earth and ball pull each other and that should decrease the speed of ball and make it 0 m per sec after infinite time and after that it must also pull towards it that means can we say after infinite time after throwing ball ,  the ball will again return to earth